# Document Set - sort by Content Type?

Tags: document-library, content-type, document-set

I have a SharePoint site where we use document sets.
I would like to sort the inner view by content type.  Is this possible? (i know through the GUI it is not possible)

thanks

I am able to create a view with different sorts.  I am not however able to sort by 'content type' within a view of a document set.  I have not idea why this would not be available.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to use a specific view within the document set - do you mean if you create a view that sorts by Content Type then you cannot select that view to be the view within the Document Set?

Comment: I am able to create a view with different sorts. I am not however able to sort by 'content type' within a view of a document set. I have not idea why this would not be available.

Comment: Ah - you mean by clicking on the column heading?  This is standard - you cannot do that in any view.

Comment: Well, when 'modify view' and scroll down to 'sorting' you can sort by a number of other columns just not content type...seems really odd

Comment: I agree - it may be down to the way Content Type is indexed.  In fact, as I recall, the standard Content Type cannot be used for search refiners either.

Comment: I don't think how it is indexed has any impact. I don't think it is possible but that seems very odd.  Seems like it would be needed functionality.